# SQL Server / T-SQL : Raiserror cancels prior inserts

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

In a procedure, I want to make a test then `Raiserror` when it's actually the case. But before that, I want to log the error in a table. My code is like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc
    @val VARCHAR(50)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT OFF;

    DECLARE @test VARCHAR(50)

    SELECT @test = test  
    FROM test_table 
    WHERE ...

    IF @test IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO log_table VALUES (@val);
        RAISERROR ('Invalid value : %i', 16, 1, @val);  
    END
END
```

The code compiles. When executed with a bad value, the error is raised, but the insert is cancelled.

I tried turning `xact_abort` and `nocount` on and off but had no luck.

I tried encapsulating the insert request in `BEGIN TRANSACTION/COMMIT` but still get the same result.

What I noticed, my `log_table` which has an auto-increment id, gets incremented even when those inserts are being cancelled.

How can I raise and error but still persist the insert request?

Thanks

Comment: No-repro. The value appears in the table. Do you have client-side code that starts and rolls back the transaction?

Comment: You were right. Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `THROW` instead:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.log_table (val varchar(50));

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[proc] @val varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN


    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT OFF;


    DECLARE @test varchar(50); --As i never set this, it'll go into the IF

    IF (@test IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO log_table
        VALUES (@val);
        THROW 51000, N'Invalid value.', 1;

    END;

END;
GO
EXEC dbo.[proc] @val = 'Some Value';

GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.log_table;
GO


DROP PROC dbo.[proc];
DROP TABLE dbo.log_table;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=70da2217c67f98b38ef4468afa20a160)

Comment: You're right, @GSerg ([DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3c8dfa940a154810f731cd9947846a9d)). I had *foolishly* assumed the OP had provided code that replicated the "problem". Silly me. ‍♂️

Comment: Both your code and mine were working in sqlserver side. The problem was from app layer rollback. Check my answer

Answer (score 2):

In order to write to a log table you have to rollback any pending transaction.  Otherwise your log table INSERT may be rolled back by the calling code, or may fail because the transaction is doomed.

So something like:

```
CREATE Procedure myproc 
    @val varchar(50)
as
begin
    set nocount on
    set xact_abort on

    begin transaction;
    begin try
       -- do stuff

       commit transaction;
    end try
    begin catch
      if @@trancount > 0 rollback;

      declare @error_message varchar(max) = error_message()
      INSERT INTO log_table values (@val);

      throw;
    end catch
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, my procedure was working as expected in SQLServer side. The problem was that I was calling this procedure from Java/Spring native query method and had to be annotated with @Modifying and @Transactional since it's doing insertions. Thus when an exception is caught, it was automatically rolled back.

I didn't find a quick solution to bypass Spring's transaction. Now I think all I have to do is, catch the exception in App layer and log to the log_table in app layer too